# How Qt Standard Support works?

Tags: qt

I beginner question...

I was wondering, how I could get in contact with `Qt` devs to get support in case I could not find any answer here or on any other site, forum, etc.

While reading here: https://www.qt.io/qt-support/

> Standard Support Granted to all Qt license holders*

Looks like support is available only to people who bought their license, and reading here:

https://www.qt.io/pricing

Looks like their 'cheapest' plan is `$302/mo.`

This price is for companies or there is a different plan for individual developers?

Suppose I buy this plan, I'll be able to mail the support only for a month, or as now I'm a 'license holder' I'll be able to get support even when the plan finishes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot buy it for a month, it's prepaid for 1 year in advance. I also think you won't be able to get perpetual support as the license itself is not perpetual, it's a subscription.

Moreover, the cheapest "Qt for Application Development"/"Professional" license only lists "Install support" in its features, not "Standard Support".

The minimal "Qt for Application Development" plan which includes "Standard Support" is $341/mo with 1-year prepayment, which results in $4090 at the very least. I'm not sure what extra charges and taxes apply and whether there are any other limits that come with the license due to export restrictions, sanctions, license agreements or whatnot.